# Gravity Forms redirects to different tab on page when required field not populated?

Tags: wordpress

I have a Gravity Form embedded in a tab on a WordPress page.  The form is on the 4th tab.

The form is gathering text data and file attachments, with most of these being required for the form to submit properly.

When the form is submitted, WordPress is redirecting the user to the 1st tab on the page.  If the form is submitted without a required value, WordPress redirects to the first tab on the page, and the user never sees the error on the 4th tab telling them that the form data cannot be submitted.  I'm concerned that users will assume their failed submissions were successful.

I was able to test for the presence of values in the text fields and prevent the display of the "Submit" button by using conditional logic when required text fields are not populated, but it appears that the conditional logic cannot be applied against file attachments in the same manner as it can be applied against text fields.

How can I either (a) ensure that the form redirection goes to the 4th tab if the form submission fails, rather than redirecting to the 1st tab, or (b) test for the presence of the file attachments and hide the "Submit" button if they are not in place?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  See:  https://endurtech.com/gravityforms-submission-error-redirection/

In a nutshell, I just need to add

```
   ajax="true"
```

to the section that's calling the form from the page in WordPress.  So, the full "Tab Content" for that tab now looks like:

```
   [gravityform id="40" title="false" description="false" ajax="true"]
```